# How can I access my app's ionic-storage (localForage) from a second web view?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, localforage, ionic-storage

I have an ionic app that uses ionic-storage.  I also have a native android background service that generates a separate webview to do work outside of the ionic app.  This service needs to write to the app's storage. I am using the same config (`name` & `storeName`) for both of these storage objects but they seem to be accessing completely different spaces, I'm guessing because they are separate `WebViews`.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or know how I might be able to remedy this?

Comment: With ionic-storage do you mean LocalStorage of the app?

Comment: @Steven by ionic-storage I mean this library: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that Ionic instantiates the storage object with a different priority for storage drivers than if you just do `let storage = new Storage();` (what I'm doing in my separate background service WebView).  I was unable to get my non-ionic WebView to use SQLite correctly so I just changed the driver order for my ionic app using `driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']`.

This resulted in both the Ionic App and and the extra WebView accessing the same storage area.